# Is there anyway to attach an event to a datalist?

Tags: html, input, html-datalist

I'm trying catch an event whenever a user picks from the autocomplete list.  I've tried putting onClick event in the options tag but it never fires.

Here is the code:

```
<input id="facility_tb" class="fac_tb" type="text" title="Facility" 
placeholder="Facility" list="fac" 
onChange="alert('Change has happened')" > 
    <datalist id='fac'><option value='Andrew' >
    <option value='Ashley'>
    <option value='Apple'>
    </option>
    </datalist>
```

Comment: You need onchange in the original element.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. <input id="facility_tb" class="fac_tb" type="text" title="Facility" placeholder="Facility" list="fac" onChange="alert('Change has happened')" >
    <datalist id='fac'><option value='Andrew' ><option value='Ashley'><option value='Apple'></option></datalist>

Comment: Put your code in your question, not in your comments.

Comment: Why do you have `</option>`?

Comment: In your `onchange`, see if the entered value was in the `<datalist>`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat This works except you are not able to distinguish between a user typing the exact value of a datalist option, or them clicking on the autocomplete list